# Android disabling button on save until another button is pressed to reset it and reenable button?

Tags: android, button

I basically have a button that saves data into sharedpreferences.

What im trying to do is disable the button from future use until a reset button is pressed which clears the data from sharedpreferences and now reenables the save button.

Ive been trying to use but when i come back to the screen after saving, it is enabled again:

```
button.setEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas?

My code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {
    EditText editText, editText2, editText3;
    RadioGroup radioSexGroup, radioTargetGroup;

    Button button, resetbutton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button_Clicker());
        resetbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);
        resetbutton.setOnClickListener(new reset_clicker());
        loadSavedPreferences();

    }
    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String weight = sharedPreferences.getString("storedweight", "Your Weight");
        editText.setText(weight);
        String age = sharedPreferences.getString("storedage", "Your Age");
        editText2.setText(age);
        String height = sharedPreferences.getString("storedheight", "Your Height");
        editText3.setText(height);
        RadioButton male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
        RadioButton female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_male", false))
            male.setChecked(true);
        else
            female.setChecked(true);

        RadioButton strength = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioStrength);
        RadioButton fitness = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioGeneralFitness);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_strength", false))
            strength.setChecked(true);
        else
            fitness.setChecked(true);
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    private void saveGenderInPreference() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedId == R.id.radioMale)
            editor.putBoolean("is_male", true);
        else
            editor.putBoolean("is_male", false);

        editor.commit();
    }

    private void saveTargetinPreference(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        radioTargetGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioTarget);
        int selectedId = radioTargetGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedId == R.id.radioStrength)
            editor.putBoolean("is_strength", true);
        else
            editor.putBoolean("is_strength", false);

        editor.commit();

    }

    class Button_Clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if
                    (//("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"))
                        //(editText.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+") || editText2.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && editText3.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                   (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || editText2.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || editText3.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
                    ) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter values in all the fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            int age = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
            if (age < 18){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid age!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            savePreferences("storedweight", editText.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("storedage", editText2.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("storedheight", editText3.getText().toString());
            saveGenderInPreference();
            saveTargetinPreference();
            finish();

        }}

    class reset_clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); // here you get your prefrences by either of two methods
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            editText.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
            button.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have reset the values! Please enter new values before continuing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: When your "screen" initializes again, you have to check wether your preferences are saved or not and set the status for your button, during initialization

Comment: Yes i understand, this is what im trying do.

Comment: Post your code, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 class Button_Clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if
                (//("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"))
                    //(editText.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+") || editText2.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && editText3.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
               (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || editText2.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || editText3.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
                ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter values in all the fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        int age = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
        if (age < 18){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid age!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        savePreferences("storedweight", editText.getText().toString());
        savePreferences("storedage", editText2.getText().toString());
        savePreferences("storedheight", editText3.getText().toString());
        saveGenderInPreference();
        saveTargetinPreference();
        savePreferences("alreadyStored","true");
        finish();

    }}
```

and then:

```
 private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (sharedPreferences.getString("alreadyStored",null) != null)
        button.setEnabled(false);
    else
        button.setEnabled(true);

    String weight = sharedPreferences.getString("storedweight", "Your Weight");
    editText.setText(weight);
    String age = sharedPreferences.getString("storedage", "Your Age");
    editText2.setText(age);
    String height = sharedPreferences.getString("storedheight", "Your Height");
    editText3.setText(height);
    RadioButton male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
    RadioButton female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_male", false))
        male.setChecked(true);
    else
        female.setChecked(true);

    RadioButton strength = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioStrength);
    RadioButton fitness = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioGeneralFitness);
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_strength", false))
        strength.setChecked(true);
    else
        fitness.setChecked(true);
}
```

This checks if you already saved the data and sets your button enabled or not based on that

Comment: Worked great, am wondering if there is some way after they have saved it to disable clicking of the text fields and radio buttons until reset is pressed?

Comment: Yes, just follow the same principle when you check `alreadyStored`

Comment: okay i will try, ive never done it before but will give it a go.

Comment: One last thing, is there a way to add a dialog box so when reset is pressed it asks for confirmation before resetting? If no is pressed it goes back to the MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, there is `AlertDialog`. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910602/how-to-use-alertdialog

Comment: Okay will try to implement into mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if anything has been saved.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String isSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("Key", "not_saved");
    if (isSaved.equals("not_saved"){ 
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

**Edit** You can add saved preference to see if it was saved

```
public class Settings extends Activity {
    EditText editText, editText2, editText3;
    RadioGroup radioSexGroup, radioTargetGroup;

    Button button, resetbutton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button_Clicker());
        resetbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);
        resetbutton.setOnClickListener(new reset_clicker());
        loadSavedPreferences();

    }
    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String weight = sharedPreferences.getString("storedweight", "Your Weight");
        editText.setText(weight);
        String age = sharedPreferences.getString("storedage", "Your Age");
        editText2.setText(age);
        String height = sharedPreferences.getString("storedheight", "Your Height");
        editText3.setText(height);
        RadioButton male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
        RadioButton female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_male", false))
            male.setChecked(true);
        else
            female.setChecked(true);

        RadioButton strength = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioStrength);
        RadioButton fitness = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioGeneralFitness);
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_strength", false))
            strength.setChecked(true);
        else
            fitness.setChecked(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check to see it is was saved
        loadSavedPreferences();
        String isSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("isSaved", "notSaved");
        if (isSaved.equals("saved"){
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }else{
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
    private void saveGenderInPreference() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedId == R.id.radioMale)
            editor.putBoolean("is_male", true);
        else
            editor.putBoolean("is_male", false);

        editor.commit();
    }

    private void saveTargetinPreference(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        radioTargetGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioTarget);
        int selectedId = radioTargetGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedId == R.id.radioStrength)
            editor.putBoolean("is_strength", true);
        else
            editor.putBoolean("is_strength", false);

        editor.commit();

    }

    class Button_Clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if
                    (//("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"))
                        //(editText.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+") || editText2.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && editText3.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                   (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || editText2.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || editText3.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
                    ) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter values in all the fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            int age = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
            if (age < 18){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid age!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            savePreferences("storedweight", editText.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("storedage", editText2.getText().toString());
            savePreferences("storedheight", editText3.getText().toString());
            // Save a string to saved and check it within onResume. 
            savePreferences("isSaved", "saved");
            saveGenderInPreference();
            saveTargetinPreference();
            finish();

        }}

    class reset_clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); // here you get your prefrences by either of two methods
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            editText.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");
            editText3.setText("");
            button.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have reset the values! Please enter new values before continuing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this exactly do?

Comment: It disables the button when the activity is resumed.

Comment: It works, but whats happening is i am opening the activity on first time setups and the button is disabled even though the activity has never been seen before. i hope u understand.

Comment: Yes I do, I just updated my answer.  Get the string or what ever it is you are saving.  If nothing has been saved, it will equal "not_saved".  If something was saved, it will replace the "not_saved" with the saved information.  Are you using a string?

Comment: Ive posted my code, im saving a few things as u can see, strings and booleans.

All i need is after that save is pressed, it gets disabled so that the user cannot change the values until reset is pressed which clears the form and reenables the button

Comment: I just updated the code to save a string stating it has been saved.  if the sting = "saved" the button will be disabled.

Comment: Am getting an error here, sharedPreferences is giving an error.       String isSaved = sharedPreferences.getString("isSaved", "notSaved");